# How to integrate external scripts to react such as PayPal Smart Check out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

So I'm trying to add paypal smart checkout to a react app and I seem to not be able to do it. The problem seems the script does load for the fist couple of seconds then immediately trows error saying the script does not exist when a second ago it was there

I have tried what a guy on youtube suggested for loading third party libraries but to no avail. I get that problem, I tried several other ways suggested but really this is the best approach and it still fails

App.js------------------------

```
import React, {Component}from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Paypp from './pyapalload'


class App extends Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      hotelname:'',
    }
  }


  render() {
    //console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        Hl
        <Paypp/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

---

### second js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class paypalload extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={

        }
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(){
        return false;
    }
    componentDidMount(){
            this.paypa=new paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    render(){
        //console.log(paypal);
    return(
        <div>
            Test
            <div id="paypal-button-container" ></div>
        </div>
    )
    }
}


export default paypalload;
```

And the script is loaded from the public/index.html 
If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the script is loaded from public/index.html" . What is a `paypal` object you are instantiating in `componentDidMount` in second js file, where is it imported, that would throw a reference error since its nowhere in the file?

Comment: I mean the script tags with source to PayPal  file is loaded asynchronously from index.html

Comment: You cannot use it in this manner then. Check out how to import 3rd party libraries into webpack projects here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

Comment: If you place a window.alert(paypal) inside of that componentdidmount that you mention you get the alert meaning PayPal exist at some point in time

Comment: Ok I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

None of the JS provided by PayPal to render smart payment buttons is intended to be run server-side.  It is all client-side code, so your App should merely serve it to the browser, to be executed there.

You can get it working in a .html file first if this simplifies your development, conceptually, and then determine how to best have your node app serve up that client-side HTML/JS